# Fetching data from JSON and displaying it

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch the contents of a static JSON file and display it in react.js.  I'm basing my code on the examples given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291822/fetch-data-from-json-file-in-react-js)
The code compiles, but when I open the page in a browser, I get this error message:

```html
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
```

Here's my component:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserList extends Component {

    async getData(){
       const res = await fetch('/static/users.json');
       const data = await res.json();
       console.log("Got Data : " + data.length);
       return this.setState(
            {data:data}
       );
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
       this.getData();
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <ul>{this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item.title}</li>)} </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: there is no constructor function with state initialised

Comment: I think you're returning the `setState` function, but not actually calling it. You can run `setState` from the async function, so just remove `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData` is an asynchronous function, as well as `setState`. This creates a race condition between the time your component mounts, to the time it renders. Therefore you need to null check.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserList extends Component {

    async getData(){
       const res = await fetch('/static/users.json');
       const data = res.json();
       console.log("Got Data : " + data.length);
       return this.setState(
            {data:data}
       );
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
       this.getData();
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <ul>{this.state && this.state.data && this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item.title}</li>)} </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the null check and I still get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: It appears that this.state itself is null, not just this.state.data

Comment: Ok, it also appears I wasn't unpacking the JSON data with await quite correctly. So, with that fix and Levi's fix, I've got it working.   so I replaced the first couple lines in getData() with :        const data = await fetch('/static/users.json').then(res => res.json());

Answer (score 0):

Its because setState internals update asynchronously and may not be set by the time your code tries to read data.

You could do:

```
 render(){
    return (
      <ul>{this.state.data && this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item.title}</li>)} </ul>
    )
}
```

This will only try and map over your array if `this.state.data` is not equal to null.

*** EDITED ****

You have also not constructed your state which is why the null check isn't working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Don't call this.setState() here!
   this.state = { 
      data: null,
   };
 }

async getData(){
   const res = await fetch('/static/users.json');
   const data = await res.json();
   console.log("Got Data : " + data.length);
   this.setState({data});
}

componentDidMount()
{
   this.getData();
}

render(){
    return (
      <ul>{this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item.title}</li>)} </ul>
    )
}
}

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state declaration is missign:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserList extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };
  
  // ...
}

export default UserList;
```